# Uncaught Error: Minified React error #130;

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In localhost, my website works fine. But when I deploy it, it shows this error and the website became blank. I have 5 pages. 4 pages work fine. But when I click on the About page, it throws this error.

**Screenshot** :
[Uncaught Error: Minified React error #130.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXOhb.png)

I tried every possible way to solve it but failed. It works on my machine but doesn't work online. I tried to debug but No error was found in localhost. Im using **Vite.**

```js
    export default defineConfig({
      plugins: [react()],
      mode: "development",
      build: {
        minify: false,
      }
    });
```

Comment: did you try running the production build on your localhost?
`vite build` then `vite preview`

Comment: [This](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2139) might help. It's a lengthy read, but one (recent) item of note is [this one](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2139#issuecomment-1444125268).

Comment: Same problem here. Did you get it fixed?